# UITableView cell reordering drag action unexpectedly stops

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift2

I'm trying to figure out how to debug the following scenario to understand why UITableView cells won't re-order.

1. Touch 'Edit' menu item, to put table view into edit mode.
2. Edit mode works for deleting cells.
3. Try to re-order cells by touching and dragging the re-order control on a cell.
4. Cell outline moves in the drag direction a couple of pixels, but then snaps back into it's original position even through my finger is still dragging across the screen.

In code:

- UITableViewDelegate: targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath never gets called.  This would seem consistent with the UI feedback for the cell snapping back to it's original position before it ever gets on top of another cell.
- UITableViewDataSource: canMoveRowAtIndexPath returns true for all rows.
- UITableViewDataSource: moveRowAtIndexPath always gets called as soon as the cell snaps back to it's original position, and the sourceIndexPath and destinationIndexPath values are the same. -

The same view controller code and storyboard work correctly for reordering cells in another project.

I've searched stackoverflow and Google for a day and can't find any reference to what would cause a cell drag event to get canceled.

Any thoughts on how I could approach debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Need more code of your TableViewController

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer, and it had nothing to do with the UITableView code.

My code has a programmatically created root view controller that handles showing/hiding a sliding menu panel.

The viewDidLoad() of this view controller creates a panGestureRecognizer to track swipes for showing/hiding the sliding menu.  This panGestureRecognizer was not passing through touches.

Adding this code fixed the problem:

```
panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue, and found the solution in my case was to add the various swipe & tap gestures on my tableview cells NOT to the cell itself, but to the contentView of the cell.

So, rather than this,

```
cell.addGestureRecognizer(myGesture)
```

the code becomes

```
cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(myGesture)
```

And that seems to work well, fixing the same sort of herky-jerky scrolling that the OP had.  Perhaps somebody can benefit from this solution, if your issue is more like the one I was having than the one the OP had.

Longer discussion of the solution can be found  here:  [Add a gestureRecognizer to a tableView cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963708/add-a-gesturerecognizer-to-a-tableview-cell)

Comment: Hey buddy, you saved my day.

Comment: @TK189  Thanks for mentioning it -- knowing that the answer was helpful *makes* my day, way beyond just the up-vote.  Cheers!