# Add a gestureRecognizer to a tableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I currently have a TableViewController with 3 cells and I'm trying to add a long press gesture recogniser to just print to the logs when detected.

I've added:

```
class TableTesting: UITableViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

and in my `tableView` method I've created a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Gesture Recognizer Testing"
    var lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressAction:")
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
    lpgr.delegate = self
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
    return cell
}
```

I've also created the function `longPressAction`:

```
func longPressAction(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Gesture recognized")
}
```

The issue I'm having is when compiling the code and trying to long press one my cells, the app is crashing and I'm getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TestingGround.TableTesting
>   longPressAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7f9afbc055d0'

I'm guessing somehow that the correct information isn't being passed into the function but I'm unsure?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `"longPressAction:"`, use the `#selector(longPressAction(_:))` notation. Using the `#selector` will give you autocomplete ability and will also warn you if you don't do something right and it cannot find the method you want.

Comment: Also, add the gesture recognizer to `cell.contentView` instead of `cell`.

Comment: So instead of what I've got, I should use: 
`let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressAction(_:)))`

Comment: @shallowThought yes the method is in the same class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you are going correct most of the way.
Use this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Gesture Recognizer Testing"
    let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressAction(_:)))
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
    lpgr.delegate = self
    cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
    return cell
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, helped a lot :) Got it working, now just need to do some checks to make sure it only prints the first time.

Comment: Do you know how I would get the cell touched within my function? So I can print something like 'cell 1 long press detected' ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressAction:")
```

Use:

```
let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressAction(gestureRecognizer:)))
```